# being able to use data with fetch api request and error checking

Tags: javascript, api, error-handling, async-await, fetch-api

Trying to make an API request with error checking and then be able to use the data from the API outside the async function. This is returning a pending promise right now. Not sure how get useable data out of the API that I can then further use throughout the program. Suggestions?

```
const fetch = require('node-fetch')

const url = 'https://employeedetails.free.beeceptor.com/my/api/path'

async function getData(url){
    try {
        const response = await fetch(url)
        if (!response.ok) {
            throw new Error ("why did I become a software engineer?");
        }
        else {
            return await response.json();
        }
    }
    catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    }
}

const data = getData(url);
console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

`async` functions return a promise. To get the usable data you will have to either `await getData(url)` (create another async function for this) or in your example you can write:

```
getData(url).then(data => console.log(data);
```

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem here is that the async function is returning a promise so you should add another asyn function to get that data, or maybe you should add a global variable before the function and then change its value